# I accidentally reset all of the user accounts while trying to set one up

Tags: login

I accidentally reset my only user accounts while trying to set another one up. When I power on my Pinebook it boots to the login screen. When I login and press enter it returns to the login screen. If I try to login again The system freezes. If I don't enter my password the second time the mouse pointer can be used to shut down the system. I have tried to hold down the left shift key at boot but it reboots to the GUI and not to the recovery. Also I am booting from an SD card. A while back I had problems and setup the SD card to boot . At that time I tried to move over to the internal but couldn't get that to work ether. If anyone can help I would appreciate the help.

Comment: You've not said what Ubuntu product/release you are using on your Pinebook.

Comment: How did you set up a new user? Are there any users inside /etc/passwd file, if you can get its contents?